# Regular expression to define some binary sequence

Tags: regex

How would you write a regular expression to define all strings of 0's and 1's that, as a binary number, represent an integer that is multiple of 3.

Some valid binary numbers would be:

```
11
110
1001
1100
1111
```

Comment: Is this your computational theory homework?

Comment: maybe you could give some background like what do you want to do and which language you want to use.

Comment: a part of it. i think i have the correct NFA but cant seem to eliminate the middle steps as its quite complicated.

Comment: dd get it. The answer is (1(01*0)*1)*0*

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Using the DFA [here](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/73dfa/) we can make a regular expression the following way, where A, B, C represent the states of the DFA.

```
A = 1B + 0A
B = 1A + 0C
C = 1C + 0B

C = 1*0B // Eliminate recursion

B = 1A + 0(1*0B)
B = 01*0B + 1A
B = (01*0)*1A // Eliminate recursion

A = 1(01*0)*1A + 0A
A = (1(01*0)*1 + 0)A
A = (1(01*0)*1 + 0)* // Eliminate recursion
```

Resulting in a PCRE regex like:

```
/^(1(01*0)*1|0)+$/
```

Perl test/example:

```
use strict;

for(qw(
11
110
1001
1100
1111
0
1
10
111
)){
    print "$_ (", eval "0b$_", ") ";
    print /^(1(01*0)*1|0)+$/? "matched": "didnt match";
    print "\n";
}
```

Outputs:

```
11 (3) matched
110 (6) matched
1001 (9) matched
1100 (12) matched
1111 (15) matched
0 (0) matched
1 (1) didnt match
10 (2) didnt match
111 (7) didnt match
```

Comment: +1. Now this is great. I had no idea you could create a regular expression that easy from a DFA.

Comment: Thank you for masterclass. I think I won't mark this task on Codewars as completed, as I wouldn't do it myself.

Answer (score 9):

When you divide a number by three, there are only three possible remainders (0, 1 and 2). What you're aiming at is to ensure the remainder is 0, hence a multiple of three.

This can be done by an automaton with the three states:

- ST0, multiple of 3 (0, 3, 6, 9, ....).
- ST1, multiple of 3 plus 1 (1, 4, 7, 10, ...).
- ST2, multiple of 3 plus 2 (2, 5, 8, 11, ...).

Now think of *any* non-negative number (that's our domain) and multiply it by two (tack a binary zero on to the end). The transitions for that are:

```
ST0 -> ST0 (3n * 2 = 3 * 2n, still a multiple of three).
ST1 -> ST2 ((3n+1) * 2 = 3*2n + 2, a multiple of three, plus 2).
ST2 -> ST1 ((3n+2) * 2 = 3*2n + 4 = 3*(2n+1) + 1, a multiple of three, plus 1).
```

Also think of any non-negative number, multiply it by two then *add one* (tack a binary one on to the end). The transitions for that are:

```
ST0 -> ST1 (3n * 2 + 1 = 3*2n + 1, a multiple of three, plus 1).
ST1 -> ST0 ((3n+1) * 2 + 1 = 3*2n + 2 + 1 = 3*(2n+1), a multiple of three).
ST2 -> ST2 ((3n+2) * 2 + 1 = 3*2n + 4 + 1 = 3*(2n+1) + 2, a multiple of three, plus 2).
```

This idea is that, at the end, you need to finish up in state ST0. However, given that there can be an arbitrary number of sub-expressions (and sub-sub-expressions), it does not lend itself easily to reduction to a regular expression.

What you have to do is allow for any of the transition sequences that can get from ST0 to ST0 then just repeat them:

These boil down to the two RE sequences:

```
ST0 --> ST0                                      :  0+
    [0]
ST0 --> ST1 (--> ST2 (--> ST2)* --> ST1)* --> ST0:  1(01*0)*1
    [1]     ([0]     ([1]    )* [0]    )* [1]
```

or the regex:

```
(0+|1(01*0)*1)+
```

This captures the multiples of three, or at least the first ten that I tested. You can try as many as you like, they'll all work, that's the beauty of mathematical analysis rather than anecdotal evidence.

Comment: I liked your explanation, btw just for clarification for those who read this answer, you need to add `^` at the beginning, in order to get a working regex.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is `(1(01*0)*10*)*`, which is the only one so far that works for `110011`

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you would.  I can't believe in any language using a regular expression could ever be the best way to do this.

Comment: i know its not the best way. I know it can be done but I just cant figure out how. It involves drawing the automata and eliminating middle states.

Comment: @Dave Webb, you can definitely do this. Actually, this is a pretty common sort of exercise in a CS Theory course, which is why I'm hesitant to answer this question.

Comment: @Dave Webb The answer is (1(01*0)*1)*0*

Comment: @unknowh yahoo, not *quite* right, that won't work for 17 * 3 = 51 (110011). You need to allow for repetitions at more levels.