# Can I use regular expressions to search for multiples of a number?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to search a big project for all examples of where I've declared an array with [48] as the size or any multiples of 48.

Can I use a regular expression function to find matches of 48 * n?

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps not, but if you can estimate how far the powers of 48 go (48^3 is six digits long, definitely huge for an array), you can search explicitly for those values.

Comment: I've realised my mistake, I meant multiples, whoops.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here you go (In PHP's PCRE syntax):

```
^(0*|(1(01*?0)*?1|0)+?0{4})$
```

Usage:

```
preg_match('/^(0*|(1(01*?0)*?1|0)+?0{4})$/', decbin($number));
```

Now, why it works:

Well we know that 48 is really just `3 * 16`.  And 16 is just `2*2*2*2`.  So, any number divisible by 2^4 will have the 4 most bits in its binary representation 0.  So by ending the regexp with `0{4}$` is equivalent to saying that the number is divisible by `2^4` (or `16`).  So then, the bits to the left need to be divisible by 3.  So using the regexp from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/867279/regular-expression-to-define-some-binary-sequence), we can tell if they are divisible by 3.  So if the whole regexp matches, the number is divisible by both 3 and 16, and hence 48...

QED...

(Note, the leading `0|` case handles the failed match when `$number` is 0).  I've tested this on all numbers from `0` to `48^5`, and it correctly matches each time...

Comment: Look up “sweet hack” in the dictionary, it will refer you to this :)

Comment: This doesn't actually work, unless OP's code declares array sizes in binary for some reason. You really want to match decimal numbers here, which is a little trickier.

Answer (score 2):

A generalization of your question is asking whether *x* is a string representing a multiple of *n* in base *b*. This is the same thing as asking whether the remainder of *x* divided by *n* is 0. You can easily create a DFA to compute this.

Create a DFA with *n* states, numbered from 0 to *n* - 1. State 0 is both the initial state and the sole accepting state. Each state will have *b* outgoing transitions, one for each symbol in the alphabet (since base-*b* gives you *b* digits to work with).

Each state represents the remainder of the portion of *x* we've seen so far, divided by *n.* This is why we have *n* of them (dividing a number by *n* yields a remainder in the range 0 to *n* - 1), and also why state 0 is the accepting state.

Since the digits of *x* are processed from left to right, if we have a number *y* from the first few digits of *x* and read the digit *d*, we get the new value of *y* from *yb* + *d.* But more importantly, the remainder *r* changes to (*rb* + *d*) mod *n.* So we now know how to connect the transition arcs and complete the DFA.

You can do this for any *n* and *b*. Here, for example, is one that accepts multiples of 18 in base-10 (states on the rows, inputs on the columns):

```
   |  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
---+-------------------------------
→0 |  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  ←accept
 1 | 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17  0  1
 2 |  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11
 3 | 12 13 14 15 16 17  0  1  2  3
 4 |  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13
 5 | 14 15 16 17  0  1  2  3  4  5
 6 |  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15
 7 | 16 17  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
 8 |  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17
 9 |  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
10 | 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17  0  1
11 |  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11
12 | 12 13 14 15 16 17  0  1  2  3
13 |  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13
14 | 14 15 16 17  0  1  2  3  4  5
15 |  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15
16 | 16 17  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
17 |  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17
```

These get really tedious as *n* and *b* get larger, but you can obviously write a program to generate them for you no problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
1|48|2304|110592|5308416
```

You are unlikely to have declared an array of size 48^5 or larger.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain what it does and add some references to it.

Answer (score 0):

No, regular expressions can't calculate multiples (except in the unary number system: decimal `4` = unary `1111`; decimal `8` = unary `11111111`, so the regex `^(1111)+$` matches multiples of `4`).

Comment: Yes they can (not in the generic sense, but definitely if it's a prime multiple of a power of 2, as 48 is -- `3 * 2 ^ 4`)...  See my answer for proof...

Comment: Very nice, but it won't be able to find multiples of 48 in his source code, will it? It has to convert them to binary first.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

# For real example,
# construction of a chain with integers multiples of 48 
# and integers not multiple of 48.
from random import *
w   =   [ 48*randint( 1,10) for j in xrange(10) ]
w.extend( 48*randint(11,20) for j in xrange(10) )
w.extend( 48*randint(21,70) for j in xrange(10) )
a = [ el if el%48!=0 else el+1 for el in sample(xrange(1000),40) ]
w.extend(a)
shuffle(w)
texte = [ ''.join(sample('     abcdefghijklmonopqrstuvwxyz',randint(1,7))) for i in xrange(40) ]
X = ''.join(texte[i]+str(w[i]) for i in xrange(40))


# Searching the multiples of 48 in the chain X
def mult48(match):
    g1 = match.group()
    if int(g1)%48==0:
        return ( g1, X[0:match.end()] )
    else:
        return ( g1, 'not multiple')

for match in re.finditer('\d+',X):
    print '%s  %s\n' % mult48(match)
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked the first `48^4 (~5.3mn)` multiples of `48`. Here are select distributions

---

`mod % 72` :: multiples of `24`

```
  1          1769472  0
  2          1769472 24
  3          1769472 48



 1            589824 0
 2            589824 24
 3            589824 48
 4            589824 72
 5            589824 96
 6            589824 120
 7            589824 144
 8            589824 168
 9            589824 192
```

---

`mod % 40` :: multiples of `8`

```
  1          1061683  0
  2          1061684  8
  3          1061683 16
  4          1061683 24
  5          1061683 32
```

`mod % 88` :: also multiples of `8`

```
   1              482583  0
   2              482584  8
   3              482583 16
   4              482583 24
   5              482583 32
   6              482583 40
   7              482584 48
   8              482584 56
   9              482583 64
  10              482583 72
  11              482583 80
```

---

`mod % 80` :: multiples of `16`

```
  1          1061683 0
  2          1061683 16
  3          1061683 32
  4          1061684 48
  5          1061683 64
```

---

`mod % 84` :: multiples of `12`

```
  1           758345  0
  2           758345 12
  3           758345 24
  4           758345 36
  5           758346 48
  6           758345 60
  7           758345 72
```

but in decimal, some interesting patterns emerge when checking last 3 digits (zero-padded below) :

- among zero-padded 3 digits those ending in `2` or `6` - the middle digit must be ***ODD**

  - When grouping middle digit by `[37] v. [159]`, only 4 groups show up in a related but non-overlapping fashion :

---

```
  [ 02468 ] [  3 7  ] [2]
  [ 13579 ] [  3 7  ] [6] 
  [ 13579 ] [ 1 5 9 ] [2]
  [ 02468 ] [ 1 5 9 ] [6]
```

---

- among zero-padded 3 digits those ending in `0` `4` or `8` — the middle digit must be ***EVEN**

  - When grouping middle digit by `[26] v. [0248]`, only 4 groups show up in a related but non-overlapping fashion :

---

```
  [ 02468 ] [  2 6  ]  [4]
  [ 13579 ] [  2 6  ] [08]
  [ 13579 ] [ 0 4 8 ]  [4]
  [ 02468 ] [ 0 4 8 ] [08]
```

putting it all  together, I'm getting ...

> ```
>  [02468]([048][0 8]|[159][6]|[26][ 4 ]|[37][2])
>  [13579]([048][ 4 ]|[159][2]|[26][0 8]|[37][6])
> ```

with a 100 % match rate against actuals

```
 jot 5308416 48 - 48 | 

 mawk '/(^|[^0-9])(0+|48|96|[0-9]*([02468]([048][08]|[159]6|[26]4|
           [37]2)|[13579]([048]4|[159]2|[26][08]|[37]6)))([^0-9]|$)/'
```

---

```
 out9: 48.4MiB 0:00:02 [19.8MiB/s] [19.8MiB/s] [ <=>]

 rows       = 5308416 | UTF8 chars = 50769348 | bytes      = 50769348
```

> Among all even numbers up to the same upper limit of 254,803,968, the `regex` filter keeps **1 in 4** numbers. Among the kept population, the actual multiples of 48 account for **1 in 6**.

> Obviously this isn't all that tight of a criteria since it's only last 3 decimal digits, but at least there weren't any false negatives (someone can go make it sign aware if they like)

Answer (score -2):

Any multiple is difficult, but here's a (python-style) regexp that matches the first 200 multiples of 48.

```
0$|1(?:0(?:08$|56$)|1(?:04$|52$)|2(?:00$|48$|96$)|3(?:44$|92$)|4(?:4(?:$|0$)|88$\
)|5(?:36$|84$)|6(?:32$|80$)|7(?:28$|76$)|8(?:24$|72$)|9(?:2(?:$|0$)|68$))|2(?:0(\
?:16$|64$)|1(?:12$|60$)|2(?:08$|56$)|3(?:04$|52$)|4(?:0(?:$|0$)|48$|96$)|5(?:44$\
|92$)|6(?:40$|88$)|7(?:36$|84$)|8(?:32$|8(?:$|0$))|9(?:28$|76$))|3(?:0(?:24$|72$\
)|1(?:20$|68$)|2(?:16$|64$)|3(?:12$|6(?:$|0$))|4(?:08$|56$)|5(?:04$|52$)|6(?:00$\
|48$|96$)|7(?:44$|92$)|8(?:4(?:$|0$)|88$)|9(?:36$|84$))|4(?:0(?:32$|80$)|1(?:28$\
|76$)|2(?:24$|72$)|3(?:2(?:$|0$)|68$)|4(?:16$|64$)|5(?:12$|60$)|6(?:08$|56$)|7(?\
:04$|52$)|8(?:$|0(?:$|0$)|48$|96$)|9(?:44$|92$))|5(?:0(?:40$|88$)|1(?:36$|84$)|2\
(?:32$|8(?:$|0$))|3(?:28$|76$)|4(?:24$|72$)|5(?:20$|68$)|6(?:16$|64$)|7(?:12$|6(\
?:$|0$))|8(?:08$|56$)|9(?:04$|52$))|6(?:0(?:00$|48$|96$)|1(?:44$|92$)|2(?:4(?:$|\
0$)|88$)|3(?:36$|84$)|4(?:32$|80$)|5(?:28$|76$)|6(?:24$|72$)|7(?:2(?:$|0$)|68$)|\
8(?:16$|64$)|9(?:12$|60$))|7(?:0(?:08$|56$)|1(?:04$|52$)|2(?:0(?:$|0$)|48$|96$)|\
3(?:44$|92$)|4(?:40$|88$)|5(?:36$|84$)|6(?:32$|8(?:$|0$))|7(?:28$|76$)|8(?:24$|7\
2$)|9(?:20$|68$))|8(?:0(?:16$|64$)|1(?:12$|6(?:$|0$))|2(?:08$|56$)|3(?:04$|52$)|\
4(?:00$|48$|96$)|5(?:44$|92$)|6(?:4(?:$|0$)|88$)|7(?:36$|84$)|8(?:32$|80$)|9(?:2\
8$|76$))|9(?:0(?:24$|72$)|1(?:2(?:$|0$)|68$)|2(?:16$|64$)|3(?:12$|60$)|4(?:08$|5\
6$)|5(?:04$|52$)|6(?:$|0$))
```