# Regex for binary multiple of 3

Tags: regex, binary

I would like to know how can I construct a regex to know if a number in base 2 (binary) is multiple of 3. I had read in this thread [Check if a number is divisible by 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/844867/check-if-a-number-is-divisible-by-3) but they dont do it with a regex, and the graph someone drew is wrong(because it doesn't accept even numbers). I have tried with: ((1+)(0*)(1+))*(0*) but it doesn't works for some values. Hope you can help me.

UPDATE:
Ok, thanks all for your help, now I know how to draw the NFA, here I left the graph and the regular expresion:

In the graph, the states are the number in base 10 mod 3.

For example: to go to state 1 you have to have 1, then you can add 1 or 0, if you add 1, you would have 11(3 in base 10), and this number mod 3 is 0 then you draw the arc to the state 0.

[image: Whiteboard version]

`((0*)((11)*)((1((00) *)1) *)(101 *(0|((00) *1 *) *0)1) *(1(000)+1*01)*) *`

And the other regex works, but this is shorter.

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Does it really have to be a regex? Checking for divisibility would be easier

Comment: Does it fall in P or NP problem?

Comment: To check if a binary number is divisible by 3, count the number of non-zero odd positions bits and non-zero even position bits from the right. If their difference is divisible by 3, then the number is divisible by 3.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If I may plug my solution for [this code golf question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/3503/hard-code-golf-regex-for-divisibility-by-7/3580#3580)! It's a piece of JavaScript that generates regexes (probably inefficiently, but does the job) for divisibility for each base.

This is what it generates for divisibility by 3 in base 2:

`/^((((0+)?1)(10*1)*0)(0(10*1)*0|1)*(0(10*1)*(1(0+)?))|(((0+)?1)(10*1)*(1(0+)?)|(0(0+)?)))$/`

<s>Edit: comparing to Asmor's, probably *very* inefficient :)</s>

Edit 2: Also, this is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/867279/regular-expression-to-define-some-binary-sequence).

Comment: It covers a whole lot more cases though!

Answer (score 68):

I know this is an old question, but an efficient answer is yet to be given and this question pops up first for "binary divisible by 3 regex" on Google.

Based on the DFA proposed by the author, a ridiculously short regex can be generated by simplifying the routes a binary string can take through the DFA.

The simplest one, using only state A, is:

`0*`

Including state B:

`0*(11)*0*`

Including state C:

`0*(1(01*0)*1)*0*`

And include the fact that after going back to state A, the whole process can be started again.

`0*((1(01*0)*1)*0*)*`

Using some basic regex rules, this simplifies to

`(1(01*0)*1|0)*`

Have a nice day.

Comment: This should be the chosen one

Comment: For the "basic regex rules", the reason the initial `0*` was removed is explained here: https://youtu.be/xLp36MhQ_D8?t=411 ... As for where the `| 0` came from, it is because `(a*b*)* = (a | b)*`.

Answer (score 0):

For some who is learning and searching how to do this:

1. see this video:
   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SmT1DXLl3f4&t=138s
2. write state quations and solve them with Axden's Theorem
3. The way I did is visible in the image-result is the same as pointed out by user @Kert Ojasoo. I hope i did it corretly because i spent 2 days to solve it...
4. [image: Solution]

Comment: Considering, that the string might be long and repeat (check this Kata:https://www.codewars.com/kata/54de279df565808f8b00126a/train/java) the complete REGEX should be:  ^(1(01*0)*1|0)*$

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, vote up the answers that you find helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30830957)

Comment: Your answer does not add anything to the existing one from @KertOjasoo, as you write yourself. Please do not add answers that essentially already exist.

Answer (score -2):

n+2n = 3n. Thus, 2 adjacent bits set to 1 denote a multiple of 3. If there are an odd number of adjacent 1s, that would not be 3.

So I'd propose this regex:

```
(0*(11)?)+
```

Comment: Actually, I'm wrong. 2 adjacent ones is sufficient, but not necessary, e.g. 9 = 1001. My bad.